# Changing font breaks linebreaks and hbox

Tags: fonts, pdftex

For learning purposes I am trying to build a basic minimal document with a changed font:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{courier}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

But it looks like this:

[image]

The text clearly goes over the 2cm border on the right I want, and depending on the text it can even go beyond the border of the paper. I also get hbox warnings.

If I use the default font it works just fine, so I think it has to do with that.

Whats am I doing wrong?

Comment: by default monospace fonts are not hyphenated and the inter-word space does not stretch so there is no way to justify the text. use `\raggedright` (also use `article` not `minimal` for test examples, `minimal` is very minimal and often creates issues due to incomplete setup)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, the core problem really does come back to monospaced fonts and `\raggedright` makes it as expected. `minimal` still works for my usecase, but ill keep it in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default monospace fonts are not hyphenated and the inter-word space does not stretch so there is no way to justify the text. Use `\raggedright` to stop justifying the text.